# Paper-tabs selection bar randomly visible when individual paper-tab data binded via Angular.dart?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, angular-dart, paper-elements

The paper-tab somehow wrongly calculates the width of selection bar to be 0px, possibly due to the data being bound at a later point because of Angular.dart bindings. Is there an event which we can fire or hook on to, in order to let polymer calculate the right width?
here's the sample code:

```
<paper-tabs>
     <paper-tab>{{angularVariable}}</paper-tab>
     <paper-tab ng-repeat="{{anotherAngularVariable in angularList}}">{{anotherAngularVariable}}</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```